# How can I customize org-agenda-write output with icons or faces?

Tags: emacs, highlight, org-mode

I am trying to customize org-mode to visually highlight output for certain items when I use `org-agenda-write` to export to pdf.  I have found `org-agenda-category-icon-alist` which looks promising, but didn't quite pan out.

I configured `org-agenda-category-icon-alist` to display icons (pngs) in the agenda successfully but when I send it to a pdf using `org-agenda-write`, the icons don't appear there.

Is there any way I can make the icons appear in the pdf output?  Or some other mechanism I can use to let me customize the look of printed agenda items, based on, e.g. tags?

Comment: It looks like the icons show up when I use `org-agenda-write` to produce html, so I'm going to work on using that and then wkhtmltopdf to convert that to pdf.  It feels kludgy but works.